# Jquery validation plugin change message color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not use errorContainers setting because plugin automatically displays messages. This is my validator:

```
        formIdentifiersFields.validate({
            highlight: function (element) {
                var elem = $(element);
                elem.closest("div.form-group").removeClass("has-success");
                elem.closest("div.form-group").addClass("has-error");
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                var elem = $(element);
                elem.closest("div.form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                elem.closest("div.form-group").addClass("has-success");
            }
       });
```

And rules is adding like this:

```
        $("#val-" + id.substr(1)).rules('add', {
            required: true, messages: {
                required: "Некорректная информация"
            }
        });
```

But now I need to make the output messages font smaller and the output messages  text color red. How make it?

Comment: Change the CSS of the `has-error` / `has-success` class.

Comment: if I understand correctly, these messages are embedded plug-in functionality - no CSS styles

Comment: The styling of the messages is done with CSS that is why the JavaScript is adding a different class depending on if the field is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may edit the css of the classes has-error and has-success and set the 'color' and 'font-size' properties with the values that you want.

Another way is to add the styles inline with jquery with the method .css().
[Here you have examples of this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

Good luck!